# How to configure Intellij

Tags: go, intellij-idea, gopath

I have a [skaffold](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/skaffold) Go project which I cloned. Now I want to run this Go project.
I had set up the configuration in project setting and GOPATH is also correctly set.
I am getting error while setting this configuration.

[image]

These are my GOPATH settings

[image]

Sometimes it runs and some time it shows the above error.

Comment: First, you need to change "Run kind" to package.
Also is the"invalid" file present and not corrupted?

Comment: Great Andrew that helped in eliminating invalid configuration error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great comment by Andrew, I would jot it down to the solution.

While adding configuration change the **Run-Kind** to package instead of file or directory.
Use this run-kind option wisely.